# VBA error '1004' when accessing cell values within 2 loops

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, listbox, userform

I recently got started with VBA...I am working on an Excel UserForm.  I want certain fields in a listbox to be selected automatically when the user makes a change in a combobox.  Although I am doing nothing out of the ordinary it still returns the "Application-defined or object-defined error".

I have searched other questions regarding this error and none of them seem to apply to the same kind of problem.  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

'first get the current row rule id
lastRow = FindLastRow("Rows Rules")

Dim id, i, k As Integer

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Sheets("Rows Rules").Cells(i, 2) = ComboBox1.Text Then
        id = Sheets("Rows Rules").Cells(i, 1)
    End If
Next


'get ISINs for id
With Sheets("Row ISINs")

    'loop  for every isin
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount
        isin = ListBox1.List(i, 0)
        'check if exists
        lastRow = FindLastRow("Row ISINs")
        'loop to compare  with every record
        For k = 1 To lastRow
            If .Cells(k, 0) = id Then 'error happens here--------------
                If .Cells(k, 1) = isin Then
                    'mark those as selected
                    ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Next

End With
End Sub
```

It appears that after the second loop:

> For k = 1 To lastRow

every access to the cells I make returns the error

I also tried checking using MsgBox:

> MsgBox .Cells(0, 1)

and it still returns the same error.

I do not know if it has to do with the loops, or something else that I'm missing.  Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no **row 0** or **column 0** in excel. If you want first row or first column, It **should start from 1** as follow:

```
.Cells(1,1)
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks, Typical of me to get stuck on such a simple error!.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The reason is `cells(k, j)` specifies a cell using k = row and j = column

you must not handle it like an array where the first value is 0.

k and j must be >= 1.